# Proof verification: in a finite dimensional normed space all norms are equivalent.

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces

I wanted to prove equivalence of norms in finite dimensional normed spaces without using Heine-Borel in arbitrary spaces.

Let $(E, ||.||)$ be a finite dimensional normed space. In the process of proving every finite dimensional normed space is complete, I was able to construct a linear homeomorphism $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to E$ which is just the mapping from a vector of coordinates to the element of $E$ with said coordinates in a finite basis of $E$.

I then tried extending this result to prove the equivalence of any two norms on $E$, but it turned out to be rather simple and makes me question whether I'm missing something:

Let $||.||_a$, $||.||_b$ be two norms on $E$. By the previous comment, I know there exist two linear homeomorphisms:
$$T_a : (\mathbb{R}^n, ||.||_2) \to (E, ||.||_a)$$
$$T_b : (\mathbb{R}^n, ||.||_2) \to (E, ||.||_b)$$
And I can write the identity function as a composition of these two:
$$T_b \circ T_a^{-1} = id: (E, ||.||_a) \to (E, ||.||_b)$$
Since the composition two homeomorphisms is again an homeomorphism, it follows that the identity function is a homeomorphism, and that $||.||_a$ and $||.||_b$ are equivalent.

Is my proof correct? Any thoughts/comments are greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How do you know a linear bijection $T:\Bbb{R}^n\to E$ is a homeomorphism? Compactness of the unit sphere is crucial here.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Correct, but the compactness of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ not $E$. What I wanted to avoid is using Heine-Borel in $E$/compactness of the unit sphere in $E$.

Comment: Sure, that's possible but you haven't mentioned how you're using compactness of $\Bbb{R}^n$'s unit sphere (relative to the Euclidean 2-norm).

Comment: @peek-a-boo I just used Heine-Borel in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: ok… btw I’m not saying what you did is wrong, just that the answer to “but it turned out to be rather simple and makes me question whether I'm missing something” is that all the ‘subtlety’ is in the careful reduction of the general case to an application of Heine-Borel in $\Bbb{R}^n$. So, if you know the details of what you did there, then good. The rest is indeed as simple as you say. Otherwise, you need to do more work and clarify your reasoning for $T$ itself being a homeomorphism. (The main part of this theorem lies in proving all norms on $\Bbb{R}^n$ are equivalent.)

Comment: I see. My construction of $T$ is fine, so I would say we're good. Thanks for your input!